# Risks sending emails with my servers using clients' SMTP credentials

Tags: email, smtp, blacklist

Assuming I am creating an online service that allows my clients to send email (using their SMTP credentials), what risks should I consider and how to prevent them?

The sender of the emails will always be the username of the SMTP credentials.

My biggest concern is the possibility of my servers being blacklisted if my clients send spam. Can this happen even if the SMTP server is not mine but my servers act as a simple "email client" and if yes, how can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your primary concern here? There appear to be multiple problems.

Comment: Hoarding access credentials isn't a good idea, generally. You should check out [Sender Rewriting Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme) where there's no need to use your clients' credentials.

Comment: You are also missing some crucial details. Like, are you running the email server, or are you just an intermediary? Who is providing the email service?

Comment: Emails block lists are not populated by the *account* but by the *server*.  Please review how email block lists work. I think that answers most of your question.

Comment: @schroeder I'm just an intermediary, I would not run the email server. Imagine an email client like Mozilla Thunderbird but as an online service, that is what I am doing. I read about email block lists but couldn't figure out if there are risks for me.

Comment: The SMTP server is blocked. Not the client that accesses it...

Comment: @schroeder perhaps I explained myself wrong, by SMPT credentials I mean the ones you enter in your mail client (Apple Mail or Outlook or Thunderbird) to send and receive emails. These include: host, password, username. My server, using these credentials, will send emails. Exactly as your mail client (Apple Mail or Outlook or Thunderbird) does.

Comment: No, I understood. My comment stands. It is possible that you have some misunderstandings about how email clients and servers work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send mail using client credentials, you will certainly use the SMTP protocol with authentication, to send the mail to the client mail host. In one of your clients sends too much spam and triggers a spam detection filter on their host, **your** server will be blacklisted on that host. That means that all of your clients that would use the same host will have their (legitimate) mails rejected. Your server will functionally be a mail relay, so you are supposed to implement spam detection on it if you do not want it to be blacklisted.

That being said, your server will have to know the client mail passwords to be able to send mail. That means that you will be responsable for the security of personal and secret data. If one of your clients find their mail account compromissed, you could have to prove that the credentials cannot have been leaked from your system. Said differently, my opinion is that the possible legal outcomes should be considered...

Comment: Theoretically, you could implement the SMTP authentication as a pass-through so it's never stored on your own servers, just something your customers pass through your API (this does not alleviate your reputation risk; search for [email deliverability](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=email+deliverability)). Make sure you're not logging so verbosely that you capture the passwords!

Comment: @AdamKatz: You are right. You still have to prove that you never stored it on purpose or in any log, and that your server were not compromissed to allow an attacker to peep at the password from the application itself. As far as I am concerned, I prefere for the systems I am in charge to never know client data not related to what I directly provide...

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming I am creating an online service that allows my clients to
> send email (using their SMTP credentials), what risks should I
> consider and how to prevent them?

I'm going to infer that the question is, "What risks exist in creating a web application that utilizes a third-party SMTP service?"

You mention already that you're not using your own SMTP service, so you have a layer of concern to worry about prior to the possible IP Block listing. Will you be allowing your users to specify their own SMTP service provider? Or will you be using a dedicated third-party provider?

**Risks**

- SMTP provider may have e-mail throttling in place (i.e. 1000 e-mail sent per 1 day)
- SMTP provider may block SMTP requests coming from your web application
- The IP Address of your web application is block listed, **which can indeed still happen even if the SMTP servers that you are using are not yours**. Typically, e-mail headers will contain details of the origin of the e-mail in the X-Originating-IP e-mail header.
- Stolen credentials can be used to send spam, or malicious e-mail.
- User credentials may be at risk of theft if logged or stored in an insecure manner.
- Poorly configured headers. You'll need to put the e-mail together programmatically before sending to the SMTP server. Poorly configured email headers can lead to rejected e-mail.

**Recommendations**

- Use Multi-factor authentication, or an additional authentication mechanism, along with SMTP authentication.
- Use a dedicated, third-party SMTP provider and ensure you understand what they do and do not allow. Verify if they throttle e-mail, and what that throttling is.
- Throttle the ability to send e-mail by your users (i.e. 1000 e-mail sent per 1 day), within your third-party provider limits.
- Don't store your users credentials.
- SPF, DKIM, and DMARC are DNS frameworks that provide additional security and reporting capabilities related to e-mail; I would highly recommend you understand how your SMTP provider has these configured.

**Recommended Reading**
SIMPLE MAIL TRANSFER PROTOCOL - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821.html

Sender Policy Framework (SPF) for Authorizing Use of Domains in E-Mail, Version 1 - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408.html

DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Signatures - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html

Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting, and Conformance (DMARC) - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html